# Laravel: Syntax error or access violation cause I use 'order' like a field too

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I get this error when laravel execute one query.

**The function is this:**

```
public function updateOrder(Request $request)
   {

       $queryParams = [];

       $ids = $request->ids;


       //el query será definido en su totalidad de forma manual
       $query = 'UPDATE projects SET order = CASE id ';

       //agregamos cada parámetro de orden y de id al array para respetar las convenciones de PDO
       foreach ($ids as $order => $id) {
           $query .= 'WHEN ? THEN ? ';
           $queryParams[] = (int) $id;
           $queryParams[] = (int) $order;
       }

       //por último agregamos los ids implicados en el update
       $queryParams = array_merge($queryParams, $ids);

       //generamos los ? necesarios para el array de ids en el query PDO
       $whereInArray = array_fill(0, count($ids), '?');
       $whereInString = implode(", ", $whereInArray);

       //agregamos dicho string generado al query final
       $query .= "END WHERE id IN ($whereInString)";

       //realizamos el update
       DB::update($query, $queryParams);
   }
```

I think I know where is the problem, my field is called order and I think order it's reserved by Laravel.

I have all my application using field 'order'.

I try it to change it for example to 'ordering' and it's works, but I can't change all the project.

How can I do it, to use order?

**The errors looks like here:**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''projects' SET 
'order' = CASE 'id' WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHE' at 
line 1 (SQL: UPDATE 'projects' SET 'order' = CASE 'id' WHEN 25 THEN 0 
WHEN 23 THEN 1 WHEN 26 THEN 2 WHEN 19 THEN 3 WHEN 27 THEN 4 WHEN 18 
THEN 5 WHEN 28 THEN 6 WHEN 14 THEN 7 WHEN 24 THEN 8 WHEN 20 THEN 9 
WHEN 12 THEN 10 WHEN 13 THEN 11 WHEN 17 THEN 12 WHEN 29 THEN 13 WHEN 
15 THEN 14 WHEN 21 THEN 15 WHEN 16 THEN 16 WHEN 22 THEN 17 WHEN 4 
THEN 18 WHEN 3 THEN 19 WHEN 1 THEN 20 WHEN 6 THEN 21 WHEN 9 THEN 22 
WHEN 8 THEN 23 WHEN 5 THEN 24 WHEN 2 THEN 25 WHEN 10 THEN 26 WHEN 11 
THEN 27 WHEN 7 THEN 28 END WHERE id IN (25, 23, 26, 19, 27, 18, 28, 
14, 24, 20, 12, 13, 17, 29, 15, 21, 16, 22, 4, 3, 1, 6, 9, 8, 5, 2, 
10, 11, 7))
```

Comment: I looked to see if `projects` is a reserved word in MySQL, but it doesn't seem to be. Nevertheless most often the solution to this error is to put back-ticks around the word. It is easy to try: `UPDATE \`projects\` SET`.

Comment: Projects it's not reserved, but order yes I think.

Comment: Ah yes of course. So: `UPDATE projects SET \`order\` = CASE....`. Is it better to use back ticks everywhere?

Comment: Thanks. You think it's a good practice put  `` in all the words like name of table, name of fields, etc? Or just only when it's reserved?

Comment: You can put it like an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur if you use a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), like `from` or `order` as a column name without using backticks around it. In your case the problem is the word `order`. So Change:

```
$query = 'UPDATE projects SET order = CASE id ';
```

to:

```
$query = 'UPDATE `projects` SET `order` = CASE `id` ';
```

and it should work. Backticks escape the column names. Such names are called 'quoted identifiers'.

Some programmer's don't like to use backticks, so they use column names that clearly avoid the set of reserved words.

Comment: Appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can replace order by projects.order . it will be work